# Vlookup from another sheet and paste the result in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a help with a vlookup using vba as I was not able to find the solution on the web
The situation is I have three sheets

- Sheet 1: Lookup value in cell B3 with a name
  [Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idFMH.png)
- Sheet 2: Lookup table with column `name` and `surname`
  [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp2QD.png)
- Sheet 3: Result of the lookup value in cell B3 with `surname`
  [Sheet 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5tkr.png)

You can refer to the images for better understanding

So the value in sheet 1 is my lookup value and the surname has to be printed in the sheet 3 and the table array is in sheet 2

The code which I tried is

```
Sub nameloopkup()
    Dim name As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim myrange As Range

    name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

    myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Value
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myrange, 2, False)
    ' the query does not run and i don't know how can i print the result in sheet 3
End sub
```

This might be quiet simple for many around here. But considering my amature level to VBA, I need some guidance regarding the same.

Any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: ① What does *"the query does not run"* actually mean? ② Why don't you just use a formula? I see no need for VBA here. ③ You should get an error in this line `myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Value` because if your variable is declared as `Range` you must use `Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B")`

Comment: Why can't you use directly V-lookup formula in Sheet 3?
Do you need only VBA Coding?
my suggestion, the easy way is directly writing formula in Sheet 3.

Comment: Yes, i need to do this via VBA itself as it is just a small bit of the complete project. But how can i print the result in sheet 3? Any suggestion

Comment: Yes, i need to do this via VBA itself as it is just a small bit of the complete project. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actuall all you need to do is:

```
Sub nameloopkup()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Result As String
    Dim SearchIn As Variant 'variant to use it as array

    Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
    SearchIn = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Value 'read data into array

    On Error Resume Next 'next line errors if nothing was found
    Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, SearchIn, 2, False)
    On Error Goto 0

    If Result <> vbNullString Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Value = Result
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively just write a formula:

```
Sub NameLookUpFormula()
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B3,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could 2... There are 2 options, if you only need 1 entry of data, or if you need a whole array of data and picking each time what you need from it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub nameloopkup()

    Dim C As Range, LastRow As Long, EmptyRow As Long, i As Long, arrData
    Dim DictData As New Scripting.Dictionary 'You need to check Microsoft Scripting Runtime from references for this
    Dim wsNames As Worksheet, wsTable As Worksheet, wsSurnames As Worksheet

    'First thing, reference all your sheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsNames = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'change this as needed
        Set wsTable = .Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set wsSurnames = .Sheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    'Keep all the data in one dictionary:
    With wsTable
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on Sheet2
        i = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on Sheet2            
        arrData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, i)).Value 'keep the data on the array

        'This will throw an error if there are duplicates
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            DictData.Add arrData(i, 1), i 'keep tracking of every name's position ' also change for arrData(i, 2) if you only need the surname
        Next i
    End With

    With wsNames
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on Sheet1
        For Each C In .Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
            EmptyRow = wsSurnames.Cells(wsSurnames.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            wsSurnames.Cells(EmptyRow, 2) = DictData(C.Value) 'if you used arrData(i, 2) instead i
            wsSurnames.Cells(EmptyRow, 2) = arrData(DictData(C.Value), 2) 'If you used i
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Value
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myrange, 2, False)
```

Here is your error.  The second argument of `Vlookup` is a Range, not a String.  As a range is an object, you also need to `Set` it:

```
Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B")
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myrange, 2, False)
```